# Razor Syntax Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, web

I just started working on a project to take over an existing programmer's code. It is a fairly large ASP.NET Web Pages project that uses the Razor syntax with c#. Apparently the code works on the client's machine, however, when I load it up on my local box, I receive some syntax errors. The errors seem to indicate that it thinks its missing a curly brace toward the bottom of my code. I've narrowed down the syntax errors to the following code:

```
            @{
              string[] sOption = {"", "0"};
              var sDescription = @Id.iDescription;
              if (sDescription == null) {}
              else {sOption = sDescription.Split('.');}
             }
```

When I change the syntax to:

```
            @{
              string[] sOption = {"", "0"};
              var sDescription = @Id.iDescription;
              if (sDescription != null)
                 sOption = sDescription.Split('.');
             }
```

it works.

Any ideas why this causes a problem in the first place. Is there a problem with the parser? Is there a different of Razor that this may work with. I'm thinking my client may have a different version that I do. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: To be honest with you I think there some sort of parser problem with else statement in razor I often even get a parser error right in designer when use else although I use it properly I would suggest just going with two if statement it not the best approach but it works without error

Comment: Thanks. That sucks that you'd have to do that. I'm a long time C# and ASP.NET Web Forms programmer and this is my first foray into Razor. Sounds like it could turn out to be frustrating.

Comment: Again maybe there is a syntax difference in doing else but i was doing it like you do and had the same problem

Comment: I don't have this problem with else (you do need the braces in CSHTML)... You elude additional/surrounding content in your CSHTML, if you simply mock-up an empty view with just this code and your declarations do you get the really get this error?

Answer (score 0):

No errors in the first sample code here.

The second one has an error:
`Block statements must be enclosed in "{" and "}"`.

I have changed your sample codes to include the missing variables.

**First sample** works here

```
          var @Id = new { iDescription = (string)null};
          string[] sOption = {"", "0"};
          var sDescription = @Id.iDescription;
          if (sDescription == null) {}
          else {sOption = sDescription.Split('.');}
```

**Second sample** syntax error here

```
          var @Id = new { iDescription = (string)null};
          string[] sOption = {"", "0"};
          var sDescription = @Id.iDescription;
          if (sDescription != null)
              sOption = sDescription.Split('.');
```

Comment: The second works properly despite what the rules are and it is proper c# syntax. The first one doesn't work for me. Of course its in a larger page and surrounded by html. But making the change makes it work.

Comment: Post a minimum set of code that makes the syntax error happen then... I can not reproduce the problem here.

Comment: Okay, will do later today when I can do that.

Comment: I just checked it out and apparently my client was using the 1.xx version of Razor and I installed 2.xx. I tested the following code at the top of a brand new 2.xx project and I get a compilation error. What is up with that??: @{
          var Id = new { iDescription = "test"};
          string[] sOption = {"", "0"};
          var sDescription = @Id.iDescription;
          if (sDescription == null) {}
          else {sOption = sDescription.Split('.');}
}